Does Gods mercy contradict justice?
If you define justice as giving everyone what they deserve, then mercy is the opposite of that, either Forgiving them when they could be punished, or "multiplying" their reward. Now if you say someone deserved "mercy", that's justice and not mercy at all because they deserved it. It also can't be that God can be just at sometime and merciful at another, since that would mean he's sometimes unjust. Ditto for some kind of grander scheme of justice involving mercy. Let's not even get into fairness. If god gives mercy whenever he wants and doesn't(which he necessarily can't do for a reason, since if it were reasonable it would be called justice) then that means different people are punished differently for the same crime !

It is more accurate to define justice as giving everyone at least what they deserve. It is a minimum standard, not an exact prescription.

Justice includes in definition, full compensation. I never said everyone is just getting the least bit of what they deserve, but ALL of what they deserve.

In general, justice is granted by a third, rather uninvolved party, whereas mercy can only be granted by an involved party. In both cases, justice is achieved because in the case of mercy, the involved party could forgive the crime or wrongdoing.

But god is the one dispensing both justice and mercy. So is he both involved and uninvolved at the same time ? Mercy is unjust by definition because its only given to those who don't deserve it. Read my question. It is mercy which is incompatible with justice not forgiveness.

No, it isn't that black and white. I think it is quite clear from the hadith that Allah can forgive with His mercy, but if a person's right has been violated, the guilty party is still subject to that part of his punishment without his forgiveness.

Mercy you keep using that word but I don't think you know what that means.

Even if the Arabic terms do not correspond 100% to their English translation, I see no contradiction to the definition you gave in my explanations.

The definition of mercy is treating someone better than they deserve. This means less punishment or more reward. This is the opposite of justice. You seem to ignore that. Explain with reference to this definition.
